# php export HTML TABLE to EXCEL

Tags: php, html, excel

I got DATA generated by PHP into HTML table format and useing the following code I EXPORT to EXCEL

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="BASIC_Data.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
echo "<tbody>";

echo "<tr><td>$DATA</td></tr>";

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

it was working fine for 6 months,

NOW, I went to check and I see EXCEL is generated but no DATA.

I also checked if DATA is generated and I saw no problem.

problem is here:

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="BASIC_Data.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

I don't know what is going on. suddenly everything changed

please help

Comment: What changed? What's in `$DATA`? What's up with the occasional word in uppercase?

Comment: @Daan $DATA is ok, no problem with it, it is basically foreach loop. it was working fine for 6 months, today I see it is generated excel with no data

Comment: Can you make a var_dump of $DATA.

Comment: @Daan did that too, no issue with data. its excel header

Comment: If you open the `BASIC_Data.xls` in an editor like Notepad++ it contains valid HTML? Or in a browser? But Excel is not displaying the tabular data correctly?

I'm afraid, you are not outputting valid Excel. You're just writing HTML and relying on Excel's ability to interpret the data correctly, which might break anytime with a newer Excel version or different user settings. Try a good Excel library like [PHPExcel](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel).

Comment: @YetiCGN Damn, you are correct! I just opened. Th entire HTML with table structure is echoed. it was not like that before? why is this like that now

Comment: Since you say the output code hasn't changed, your premise that Excel will open HTML content inside an XLS file as a spreadsheet now fails. Maybe it's got to do with this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3181507 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: You are not outputting xls(x) data, but HTML. Excel can interpret tabular data in HTML, or at least used to but the correct way would be to generate a real Excel file with a decent library like [PHPExcel](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel) instead of fooling your users into thinking they're downloading an XLS file when it's just a renamed HTML file. I know, JIRA does this as well, but it's still a bad solution.

Comment: What you said is true and I agree. However, I have made the 25 functions on this and if I use PHPExcel I will have to change everything.
Is there any temp solution while I work on it.

Comment: You don't have to change everything, just the "view layer", the output - which is pretty simple in your example. Just a bunch of echo statements. So, what is happening, exactly? You get an "Excel" file, it opens in Excel fine but then it's empty?
"EXCEL is generated but no DATA. [...] I also checked if DATA is generated" So you've var_dump()ed the $DATA variable and it contains the data in HTML format?

Comment: Exactly! you read my mind. Excel file is created but not data and when I open the Excel file in Notepad it show the entire HTML Table with Data.

Comment: And this $DATA variable also has </td></tr> and <tr><td> tags in them? I quickly played around a bit with this based on what you posted and it works for me in Excel 2016. Can you post a snippet (anonymized if necessary) of the contents of $DATA so we can analyze it further?

Comment: it works, now, The issue was I think is that Microsoft has update its security. All you have to do now is to the download file and right button click and go to properties and check the UNLOCK